# SVG foreign element in chrome

Tags: html, svg

I have built a simon game ina Js/jQuery with svg graphics. It works normally in Firefox but seems broken in every other browser. It seems that the problem lies inside the foreignObject svg element. The simon game lies  in codepen.io:

http://codepen.io/gavlooth/pen/PzKYdv

Does anyone have any idea of what is going wrong?

Here is the code

```
   <div id="canvas">
     <div id="circle">

       <!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->


       <svg
       xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
       xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
       xmlns: rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22- rdf-syntax-ns#"
       xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
       xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
       width="300"
       height="300"
       viewbox ="0 0 1062.9921 1062.9921"
       id="svg2"
       version="1.1"
       inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
       sodipodi:docname="simon2 svg.svg">
         <defs
         id="defs4" />
         <sodipodi:namedview
         id="base"
         pagecolor="#ffffff"
         bordercolor="#666666"
         borderopacity="1.0"
         inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
         inkscape:pageshadow="2"
         inkscape:zoom="2.8"
         inkscape:cx="196.48829"
         inkscape:cy="174.88852"
         inkscape:document-units="px"
         inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
         showgrid="false"
         inkscape:window-width="1536"
         inkscape:window-height="801"
         inkscape:window-x="-8"
         inkscape:window-y="-8"
         inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
         <metadata
         id="metadata7">
           < rdf: rdf>
             <cc:work
              rdf:about="">
               <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
               <dc:type
                rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
               <dc:title />
             </cc:work>
           </ rdf: rdf>
         </metadata>
         <g
         inkscape:label="Layer 1"
         inkscape:groupmode="layer"
         id="layer1"
         transform="translate(0,10.629921)">
           <ellipse
           style="fill:#2f9d84;fill-opacity:0.82882882"
           id="path4149"
           cx="537.88177"
           cy="499.36212"
           rx="504.27341"
           ry="474.14215"
           transform="matrix(0.99999945,-0.00104714,0.00106105,0.99999944,0,0)" />


           <foreignObject x="300" y="300" width="500" height="400"  requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
             <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
             <div>
             <div id = "Fcontainer">
               <div id = "item1"> Simon  <span class="sup">&reg;</span> </div>
               <div id = "item2">   
                 <div id="counter">
                   <div id="dis">
                                --
                   </div>
                 </div>

                 <div id = "start">
                   <div class='btn-circle red' style="margin-top:25%">
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div id= "strict">

                   <div id='indicator-light'>
                   </div>

                   <div  id ="skata" class='btn-circle orange'>
                   </div>


                 </div>
               </div>
               <div id = "item3">
                 <div style="margin-left:12%;">
                   <div>
                     COUNT
                   </div>
                   <div>
                     START
                   </div>
                   <div>
                     STRICT
                   </div>
                 </div>

                 <div id="svg-button" style="height:70%;">
                   <svg
                   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
                   xmlns: rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22- rdf-syntax-ns#"
                   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
                   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
                   width="100%"
                   height="100%"
                   viewbox ="0 0 44.122022 44.122029"
                   id="svg4246"
                   version="1.1"
                   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
                   sodipodi:docname="button1.svg">
                     <defs
                     id="defs4248">
                       <linearGradient
                       gradientTransform="matrix(0.70155592,0,0,0.73625312,527.90634,341.60443)"
                       inkscape:collect="always"
                       xlink:href="#linearGradient3257"
                       id="linearGradient2714"
                       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                       x1="127.19796"
                       y1="18.49473"
                       x2="127.19796"
                       y2="47.546875" />
                       <linearGradient
                       id="linearGradient3257"
                       inkscape:collect="always">
                         <stop
                         id="stop3259"
                         offset="0"
                         style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1" />
                         <stop
                         id="stop3261"
                         offset="1"
                         style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:0" />
                       </linearGradient>
                       <linearGradient
                       gradientTransform="matrix(0.7015559,0,0,0.7362531,405.0492,347.31872)"
                       inkscape:collect="always"
                       xlink:href="#linearGradient3257"
                       id="linearGradient2716"
                       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                       x1="127.19796"
                       y1="18.49473"
                       x2="127.19796"
                       y2="47.546875" />



                     </defs>
                     <sodipodi:namedview
                     id="base"
                     pagecolor="#ffffff"
                     bordercolor="#666666"
                     borderopacity="1.0"
                     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
                     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
                     inkscape:zoom="11.2"
                     inkscape:cx="30.895793"
                     inkscape:cy="15.757932"
                     inkscape:document-units="px"
                     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
                     showgrid="false"
                     fit-margin-top="0"
                     fit-margin-left="0"
                     fit-margin-right="0"
                     fit-margin-bottom="0"
                     inkscape:window-width="1536"
                     inkscape:window-height="801"
                     inkscape:window-x="-8"
                     inkscape:window-y="-8"
                     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
                     <metadata
                     id="metadata4251">
                       < rdf: rdf>
                         <cc:work
                          rdf:about="">
                           <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                           <dc:type
                            rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                           <dc:title></dc:title>
                         </cc:work>
                       </ rdf: rdf>
                     </metadata>
                     <g
                     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
                     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
                     id="layer1"
                     transform="translate(-595.08187,-353.15835)">
                       <ellipse  class="identifier"
                       ry="22.061014"
                       rx="22.06101"
                       cy="375.21936"
                       cx="617.14288"
                       id="path3676"
                       style="fill:#ef2929;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
                       <ellipse  class="identifier"
                       ry="11.988996"
                       rx="15.734934"
                       cy="367.21024"
                       cx="617.14282"
                       style="opacity:0.75;fill:url(#linearGradient2714);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                       id="path3678" />
                       <g
                       style="fill:#a40000;stroke:none"
                       transform="matrix(0.58240892,0,0,0.62445042,258.47069,-114.72848)"
                       id="g3750">
                         <path
                         transform="matrix(0.935483,0,0,0.935483,3.100892,-64.47165)"
                         d="m 649.08789,892.00586 c -7.61805,2.49027 -13.14452,9.59996 -13.14453,18.05664 2e-5,10.525 8.53164,19.05663 19.05664,19.05664 10.525,-3e-5 19.05663,-8.53164 19.05664,-19.05664 -2e-5,-8.45901 -5.5512,-15.56911 -13.17578,-18.05664 l 0,6.80273 c 4.06873,2.13526 6.90625,6.34341 6.90625,11.25391 10e-6,7.04627 -5.74083,12.78711 -12.78711,12.78711 -7.04628,10e-6 -12.78711,-5.74083 -12.78711,-12.78711 -2e-5,-4.90752 2.80743,-9.1179 6.875,-11.25391 l 0,-6.80273 z"
                         inkscape:href="#path22091"
                         id="path3752"
                         style="fill:#a40000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                         xlink:href="#path22091"
                         inkscape:original="M 649.75 891.0625 C 641.40779 893.35756 635.28126 900.99292 635.28125 910.0625 C 635.28127 920.94545 644.11705 929.78124 655 929.78125 C 665.88295 929.78122 674.71874 920.94545 674.71875 910.0625 C 674.71873 900.98968 668.56549 893.35456 660.21875 891.0625 L 660.21875 899.15625 C 664.28467 901.11041 667.125 905.25095 667.125 910.0625 C 667.12501 916.75034 661.68785 922.1875 655 922.1875 C 648.31215 922.18751 642.875 916.75035 642.875 910.0625 C 642.87498 905.25102 645.6842 901.11044 649.75 899.15625 L 649.75 891.0625 z "
                         inkscape:radius="-0.66131908"
                         sodipodi:type="inkscape:offset" />
                         <path
                         transform="matrix(0.935483,0,0,0.935483,3.100892,-64.47165)"
                         d="m 651.78906,887.91406 0,22.60938 6.42188,0 0,-22.60938 -6.42188,0 z"
                         inkscape:href="#path22093"
                         id="path3754"
                         style="fill:#a40000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                         xlink:href="#path22093"
                         inkscape:original="M 651.1875 887.3125 L 651.1875 911.125 L 658.8125 911.125 L 658.8125 887.3125 L 651.1875 887.3125 z "
                         inkscape:radius="-0.60243881"
                         sodipodi:type="inkscape:offset" />
                       </g>
                       <g
                       id="g3756"
                       transform="matrix(0.58240892,0,0,0.58240892,258.47069,-82.518459)"
                       style="fill:#eeeeec;stroke:none">
                         <path  class="identifier"
                         sodipodi:type="inkscape:offset"
                         inkscape:radius="-0.66131908"
                         inkscape:original="M 649.75 891.0625 C 641.40779 893.35756 635.28126 900.99292 635.28125 910.0625 C 635.28127 920.94545 644.11705 929.78124 655 929.78125 C 665.88295 929.78122 674.71874 920.94545 674.71875 910.0625 C 674.71873 900.98968 668.56549 893.35456 660.21875 891.0625 L 660.21875 899.15625 C 664.28467 901.11041 667.125 905.25095 667.125 910.0625 C 667.12501 916.75034 661.68785 922.1875 655 922.1875 C 648.31215 922.18751 642.875 916.75035 642.875 910.0625 C 642.87498 905.25102 645.6842 901.11044 649.75 899.15625 L 649.75 891.0625 z "
                         xlink:href="#path22091"
                         style="fill:#eeeeec;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                         id="path3758"
                         inkscape:href="#path22091"
                         d="m 649.08789,892.00586 c -7.61805,2.49027 -13.14452,9.59996 -13.14453,18.05664 2e-5,10.525 8.53164,19.05663 19.05664,19.05664 10.525,-3e-5 19.05663,-8.53164 19.05664,-19.05664 -2e-5,-8.45901 -5.5512,-15.56911 -13.17578,-18.05664 l 0,6.80273 c 4.06873,2.13526 6.90625,6.34341 6.90625,11.25391 10e-6,7.04627 -5.74083,12.78711 -12.78711,12.78711 -7.04628,10e-6 -12.78711,-5.74083 -12.78711,-12.78711 -2e-5,-4.90752 2.80743,-9.1179 6.875,-11.25391 l 0,-6.80273 z"
                         transform="matrix(0.935483,0,0,0.935483,3.100892,-64.47165)" />
                         <path class="identifier"
                         sodipodi:type="inkscape:offset"
                         inkscape:radius="-0.60243881"
                         inkscape:original="M 651.1875 887.3125 L 651.1875 911.125 L 658.8125 911.125 L 658.8125 887.3125 L 651.1875 887.3125 z "
                         xlink:href="#path22093"
                         style="fill:#eeeeec;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                         id="path3760"
                         inkscape:href="#path22093"
                         d="m 651.78906,887.91406 0,22.60938 6.42188,0 0,-22.60938 -6.42188,0 z"
                         transform="matrix(0.935483,0,0,0.935483,3.100892,-64.47165)" />
                       </g>
                     </g>
                   </svg>





                 </div>
                 <div style="height:10%; display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content: space-between;">
                   <h1 id="onoff" style ="width:100%;margin-bottom:1%;">OFF</h1>
                 </div>

               </div>

             </div>
           </div>

           </body>
         </foreignObject>

         <path
         style="fill:rgb(155,0,2);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25401148px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 254.74219 151.22852 A 90.20688 102.17109 86.965732 0 1 161.13867 232.70508 L 161.2832 276.62891 A 132.65856 125.40141 0 0 0 293.52539 151.22852 L 254.74219 151.22852 z "
         transform="matrix(3.5433068,0,0,3.5433068,0,-10.629921)"
         id="path3342" />
         <path
         style="fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.90004063px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path_3342-2"
         ry="444.33566"
         rx="470.04999"
         cy="516.64783"
         cx="538.57147"
         d=""
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
         <path
         style="fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.90004063px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path_3342-3"
         ry="444.33566"
         rx="470.04999"
         cy="516.64783"
         cx="538.57147"
         d=""
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
         <path
         style="fill:rgb(0,173,173);fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.23711532px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 51.255859 152.16797 L 10.865234 152.40625 A 132.67548 125.41836 0 0 0 143.81641 277.04102 L 143.7168 232.44531 A 90.20688 102.17109 86.965732 0 1 51.255859 152.16797 z "
         transform="matrix(3.5433068,0,0,3.5433068,0,-10.629921)"
         id="path3342-8" />
         <path
         style="fill:rgb(173,158,0);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25482526px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 162.19531 10.912109 L 161.88867 52.886719 A 90.20688 102.17109 86.965732 0 1 255.52539 137.11719 L 293.92773 137.11719 A 132.65774 126.20696 0 0 0 162.19531 10.912109 z "
         transform="matrix(3.5433068,0,0,3.5433068,0,-10.629921)"
         id="path3342-9" />
         <path
         style="fill:rgb(54,100,0);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25401148px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 141.89453 10.105469 A 132.65856 125.40141 0 0 0 10.066406 135.21094 L 51.109375 135.30273 A 90.20688 102.17108 86.96573 0 1 142.18945 54.666016 L 141.89453 10.105469 z "
         transform="matrix(3.5433068,0,0,3.5433068,0,-10.629921)"
         id="path3342-27" />
         <ellipse
         ry="319.72186"
         rx="361.94296"
         cy="504.01788"
         cx="541.88934"
         id="ellipse4202"
         style="fill:#cac8e9;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.69846582px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
         transform="matrix(0.99991186,-0.01327684,0.00207067,0.99999786,0,0)" />
       </g>
     </svg>


   </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: try removing the requiredExensions attribute.

Comment: I did it, still the same ...